# Rendering json data in multiple react.js components

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I want to fetch some values from a json file and render them in multiple components. This code doesn't seem to work. Please suggest any changes. probably there are some issues with scope.

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
      return { myData: [] }

    },
    showResults: function(response){
        this.setState(
          {myData: response}
          )
    },

    loadData: function(URL) {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: URL,
        success: function(response){
          this.showResults(response)
        }.bind(this)
      })
    },

    render: function(){
      this.loadData("fileLocation/sample.json");
      return(
        <div>
        {myData.key1}
        <Component1 value={myData.key2} />
        <Component2 value={myData.array[0].key3}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
  });

  var Component1 = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return(
        <div>{this.props.value}</div>
      )
    }
  });

  var Component2 = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return(
        <div>{this.props.value}</div>
      )
    }
  });
  ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

This is sample.json file I'm trying to fetch from. Even this shows a syntax error

```
{
  key1:"value1",
  key2:"value2",
  array: [
    {key3:"value3"},
    {key4:"value4"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `myData.` be `this.state.myData.`?

Comment: Also, call `this.loadData()` in the `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`. Else, it'll infinitely call due to state change.

Comment: In addition to @Kujira tips, the `.bind(this)` is referring to the xhr object. Assign an alias to `this` outside the `$.ajax` at the beginning of `loadData` function, and then utilize the alias at the success callback to refer to the actual this that you want.

Comment: @falsarella can you please write the modified code. I am new to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly call `showResults` at `loadData` [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983158/rendering-json-data-in-multiple-react-js-components#comment61526229_36983158):

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
      return { myData: [] };
    },

    showResults: function(response){
        this.setState({
            myData: response
        });
    },

    loadData: function(URL) {
      var that = this;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: URL,
        success: function(response){
          that.showResults(response);
        }
      })
    },
```

Move `loadData` from `render` to `componentDidMount` [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983158/rendering-json-data-in-multiple-react-js-components#comment61521709_36983158), and properly access `myData` [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983158/rendering-json-data-in-multiple-react-js-components#comment61521567_36983158):

```
    componentDidMount: function() {
      this.loadData("fileLocation/sample.json");
    },

    render: function(){
      return(
        <div>
        {this.state.myData.key1}
        <Component1 value={this.state.myData.key2} />
        <Component2 value={this.state.myData.array[0].key3}/>
        </div>
      )
    }
});
```

Keep `Component1` and `Component2` as they already are:

```
var Component1 = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return(
        <div>{this.props.value}</div>
      )
    }
});

var Component2 = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return(
        <div>{this.props.value}</div>
      )
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('content'));
```

Comment: @VishnuPaspunoor Don't just copy-paste: try to understand the reasoning behind each change! :)

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll surely understand

Comment: how to do this without using jquery? Can we do this using jsx?

Comment: I am getting this error: jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/React/projects/function%20URL()%20%7B%20[native%20code]%20%7D?callback=jQuery22408908796818712801_1465293419642&_=1465293419643 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @VishnuPaspunoor You can do the ajax with any library you want, I'd recommend Zepto or Axios. Try to debug or log things to troubleshoot the error you're getting. Basically, you're trying to fetch a file or an endpoint that doesn't exist (404 Not Found). A great start point is the ajax URL - review if it's correct.

Comment: @VishnuPadpunoor Nice, thanks! I've updated the answer accordingly!